# PHP include txt file displays: "1"

Tags: php, html, include

First i want to say. i tried other ways but didnt succeed. i get white screen sometimes.

i want to display the content of the txt file.

```
    elseif($id == 0){
    $homepage_text = include 'homepage.php';
    $antwoorden .= "<h4>Welkom op JouwAntwoorden.nl</h4><br>Maak een          keuze uit de vakken die hier links staan weergeven.<br>".$homepage_text."<br>";   
    }
```

my homepage.txt is just:

```
Test
```

I hope someone can correct me.

Comment: Don't use `include`, use something like `file_get_contents()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `include` for getting contents of file. `include` for adding php code to execude. To get contents of file, without executing, use `file_get_contents`:

```
elseif($id == 0){
  $homepage_text = file_get_contents('homepage.txt');
  $antwoorden .= "<h4>Welkom op JouwAntwoorden.nl</h4><br>Maak een          keuze uit de vakken die hier links staan weergeven.<br>".$homepage_text."<br>";   
}
```